# Why are these two implementations of max in matlab different?

Tags: matlab

I want to get the max of each item in an array compared to 5. What differs between these 2 snippets?

```
values = max(values, 5);
```

and

```
values(values < 5) = 5;
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: Why do you think they are different? With `values=[1 2 5 2 7 3 5 22 1 -5];`, `values = max(values, 5);` returns `5 5 5 5 7 5 5 22 5 5`. The same result is achieved with `values(values < 5) = 5;`. The title of your post is completely misleading.

Comment: Next time, please include some sample vector `values`, remove the ; to print the result and include the result in the question, and you will more or less answer yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference if your matrix has `NaN` values:

```
>> values = [1 2 NaN -Inf Inf]
values =
     1     2   NaN  -Inf   Inf

>> max(values, 5)
ans =
     5     5     5     5   Inf

>> values(values < 5) = 5
values =
     5     5   NaN     5   Inf
```

As you see `max(NaN, 5) == 5` but since `NaN<5` is `false` the element containing `NaN` value won't be set to 5. If you want it to behave exactly like `max` you can try this:

```
>> values(~(values >= 5)) = 5
values =
     5     5     5     5   Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

In this implementation both will give the same result.

In the *general* case `max(A,B)`, the output contains the maximum of `A` or `B` at each element. The *general* equivalent would then be `A(A<B) = B(A<B);`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no difference

But with second you can't preserve your old matrix, however with first one you can if you change the output variable name.

Comment: This is not true. Both instructions change the elements of `values`.

Comment: @JackOLantern yeah, I meant it in somewhat different sense

Comment: Of course, with the second, you can preserve the original matrix with an extra assignment as  `foo = values;` and `foo(values < 5) = 5;`.

Comment: Forget it. I was in a bad mood today :)